# Preorder and Inorder of Trees with more than two children

Tags: algorithm, inorder, preorder

We know that a given preorder and inorder traversal of a binary tree uniquely defines the tree , what about general trees i.e trees which have more than two children , does the preorder and inorder traversal have a one-one correspondence to the tree structure .

In other words given a tuple (preorder,inorder) of a general tree is it unique for a general tree or there can be many trees with the same tuple of preorder and inorder traversal ?

Comment: I believe this is the question for [CS.SE](http://cs.stackexchange.com). Anyway, you should define pre-order and in-order traversals for non-binary tree.

Comment: By inorder tree traversal of a general tree I meant doing a depth first traversal of the tree and printing the nodes accordingly .

Comment: @ABHISHEK That makes no sense. You could describe pre-order traversal and post-order traversal in the same way (pre-order does a DFS and prints on entry, post-order does a DFS and prints on exit). In-order means that you visit the root after the left subtree and before the right subtree. There is no logical way to generalize that to arbitrary trees.

Answer (score 4):

In-order traversal (visit the left subtree, visit the root, visit the right subtree) is not defined for a non-binary tree (there is no left and right subtree).

Obviously, pre-order does not define the tree uniquely. There is no difference between the path `A, B, C` and the tree with root `A` and children `B` and `C`.

However, the combination of pre-order and post-order uniquely defines your tree (provided that all nodes are unique). We can show this by induction. Clearly, the empty string uniquely defines an empty tree.

Now, given a non-empty pre-order and post-order string, it is obvious that the first node in the pre-order string (and the last in the post-order) is the root `R` of the tree. All we need to do now is identify the subtrees (and corresponding pre-order and post-order string) rooted at the children of `R`, because we can find their structure by the induction hypothesis.

Let `RAaaaaaBbbbbb` be the pre-order string and `aaaaaAbbbbbBR` the post-order string (`a` and `b` are arbitrary nodes). Clearly, `A` is the root of the first child of `R`, because it is the first successor in the pre-order string. In post-order, that subtree ends at `A` (by definition of post-order). We cut off that part and see that the second child of `R` must be `B`. There are no more children of `R`, because `B` is the last node in the post-order string. We now have two smaller subproblems: `Aaaaaa`, `aaaaaA` and `Bbbbbb`, `bbbbbB`. We can solve these by the induction hypothesis.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply turn your general tree into a binary tree ( by taking a look at [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Encoding_general_trees_as_binary_trees) ) and then traverse it.